# Date field being reset to 1/1/0001 when I reset my form (jQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, bootstrap-datetimepicker

**JS for my date field:**

```
$('.datetime-entry').datetimepicker({
    format: 'n/j/Y',
    timepicker: false,
    value: new Date()
});
```

**JS that resets my form (including date):**

```
function resetForm() {
    $('#form-create')[0].reset();
}
```

When my form first loads, it has today's date. When I reset the form, the date changes to 1/1/0001.

I tried to fix this by adding
`$('.datetime-entry').datetimepicker({ value: new Date() });` to my `resetForm` function, but it still doesn't work.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** Also tried changing `resetForm` to this:

```
    function resetForm() {
        var datesValue = $('.datetime-entry').val();
        $('#form-create')[0].reset();
        $(".datetime-entry").val(datesValue);
    }
```

in the hopes that I could save the value before the form is reset and re-enter it after. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using Bootstrap DateTimePicker, then you need to provide a Default Value in the Date Picker [Bootstrap
>   DateTimePicker Manual](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date)

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").defaultDate(defaultDate)
```

Comment: Added $('.datetime-entry').data("DateTimePicker").defaultDate(defaultDate); to resetForm and still nothing changed.. did I do that wrong?